# How do I implement a ranking system like instagram?

Tags: algorithm, ranking

I am developing an app in which people can upload a TaggedImage that can be visualized by anothers.
So the thing is that I want to implement a ranking system that retrieves the data in function of how well recieved is, how new the item is, if it is shared etc,

But, I couldn't found any info that helps me as guide for. I really don't know where to start, it is from the SQL server, from the app service, or another backend service?

Where can I get more practical info about this topic?

Comment: PageRank or similar algorithms would ideally be from another backend system, with data sourced from a database

Comment: "*Where can I get more practical info about this topic?*" Questions seeking links to or recommendations for off-site resources are expicitly off-topic here per the scope of the site defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Ranking means mapping your potential items to a number i.e. finding a function `r(x): X -> R`, where `X` is your set of items, `x` is some arbitrary item from `X` and `R` is the set of real numbers.

In practice you use all kinds of information about your items, also known as *features* which has a correlation with some actual goal you are trying to optimise. You need to define your goal - it may be related to *engagement* i.e. the amount of time the user spends using your application, it could also be the amount of revenue this user generates, or the number of likes he ends up leaving during the current session.

Once you have a goal and your features, you need to build a function. It could be hand-crafted or optimised. Optimisation involves searching for parameters that maximise your objective function in order to pick the best ranking function out of some family of functions. This is in essence what Machine Learning is about.

Endless books have been written about what features you might want to use for your particular problem, what objective functions you might want to use to achieve your business objectives and what algorithms you can use to increase your chances of finding a good set of parameters.

So I won't go into a lot of details but I will give you a few pointers on each of the three issues.

**Features**

- Number of total likes for this item
- Number of likes today
- Who posted this item
- When it was posted
- How many comments were left
- Who liked the item
- The caption text
- Hashtags used
- The image itself

**Objectives**

- Engagement with the item (like, comment, dwell time)
- Engagement with the application (likes, comments, dwell time, posts)
- Item diversity

**Algorithms**

- Boosted Decision Trees
- Neural Networks
- Image Classification (for binary events, regression otherwise)

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know where all this operations requieres to be made? Any link to look more up to? I am currently use FireBase, does other database as MongoDB or other, have more freedom to deal with this kind of things, or with firebase is good enough?

Comment: This isn't a question of databases - you want to search for and learn about data science to build a ranking system. there are many courses on the internet, good luck